# Format code to display numbers in millions with trend arrow up or down based on value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to show a variance between two years in millions and cannot figure out the correct format code to show like this:

[image]

any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### CUSTOM FORMATTING WITH SYMBOLS IN EXCEL

```
[Color10] ▲ #,##0.0,,;[Red] ▼ (#,##0.0,,)
```

• **STEP 1: Select the column’s variance numbers and press CTRL + 1 to bring up the Format Cells dialogue box**

[image: STEP_1]

• **STEP 2: Select the Custom category and select a number format type – #,##0.0,,;[Red] (#,##0.0,,)**

**The first section of this code #,##0.0,, is for a positive number, and second code [Red] (#,##0.0,,) is for a negative number.**

[image: STEP_2]

• **STEP 3: Under the Type: area you will need to enter the text [Color10] at the start of the positive value string**

[image: STEP_3]

• **STEP 4: Now select a blank cell and go to Insert --> Symbol --> Font: Arial --> Subset: Geometric Shapes and then Insert the Up-Pointing Triangle ▲ and Insert the Down-Pointing Triangle ▼ and press Cancel**

[image: STEP_4]

• **STEP 5: You will need to copy the triangles, select the variance numbers, press CTRL + 1 and paste the triangles before each positive and negative value string, then press OK**

[image: STEP_5]

**You now have your custom number formats with an upwards triangle for any positive number(s) and a downwards triangle for any negative number(s)**

[image: OUTPUT]